# Reversing an integer without using reverse functions or lists

Tags: python

I've been struggling with a problem for my class, and when I came up with a solution my professor told me it was incorrect even though I got the output he was asking for while staying within the rules he set up for the problem.

The problem asks me to do the following:

> Write a Python program that reads an integer from the keyboard and write its reverse to the screen.  You need to use a for loop, don't use the reverse function or a list.

And my code looks like this:

```
num = int(input("So you like things backwards eh? Well, enter a number and 
I'll do my best: "))
Onum = str(num)
revStr = ""
for x in Onum:
  revStr = x + revStr

print("Your wish is my command! Your" , num, "looks like", revStr, "Backwards!")
```

It works for any number even ones ending in 0.

I don't know how else I would do this given the restraints. What could I have done wrong?

Comment: Yes I want an integer. But When I attempted to do this with an integer that ends in 0, the reverse output dropped the 0. I didn't know how to keep it other than turning the input into a string.

Comment: If it's an integer, the 0 will be lost, but maybe it's what your techear wants.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
def reverse(n):
    m = 0
    while n > 0:
        n, r = divmod(n, 10)
        m = 10 * m + r
    return m
```

However, for a real application, I would expect the following to be much faster:

```
def reverse(n):
    return int(str(n)[::-1])
```

---

A few other ways to try to satisfy the silly constraints given in the comments:

```
n = 45712090
s = str(n)
t = ""
m = len(s)
for i in range(m):
    t = s[i] + t
print(t)


n = 45712090
s = str(n)
m = len(s)
for i in range(m - 1, -1, -1):
    print(s[i], end="")
print()


import math
n = 45712090
m = math.ceil(math.log10(max(1, n)))
for i in range(m):
    n, r = divmod(n, 10)
    print(r, end="")
print()
```

Comment: TIL `divmod` — been doing this the hard way for  along time.

Comment: This is clear and concise and I truly thank you for this. However, I'm NOT allowed to use the reverse function for this problem.

Comment: Extra-credit department: the problem statement says "integer"; the code fails to handle n < 0.  it's unclear, though, whether we want ```-123 => 321-``` or ```-123 => -321```. The former would have to treat the sign specially, and we'd also have trouble with -MAXINT. The latter would require me to re-familiarize myself with integer division of negative numbers.

Comment: @dave-not-cutler `321-` is not an integer, and `-321` is not *exactly* the reversed integer, so I didn't consider n<0. But if the OP has a requirement about this I will have a look. By the way there is no MAXINT in Python.

Comment: I agree that it would be useful for another user needing to solve a similar problem without the same constraints. I might be misunderstanding this snippet but from what I've googled `def reverse():` calls the reverse function. 

I have to use a for loop. 

Is there a way to assign "places" to each character in an integer without converting it to a string and then printing those places individually? LIke using a range in the for loop?

Comment: @Alex Maybe I'm slow to understand, but you wanted a solution that does not make use of strings reversal (which the *second* solution in my answer does). The first solution given uses a loop and integer divisions (however, unless you have a bound on the argument, a `for` loop won't do the job as you don't know in advance how many digits there are). If you don't want to call that a function, just remove `def`. If you don't want to call it `reverse`, then call it `banana`. What's the problem?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut
I'm Sorry, 

I may have left out vital information that I wasn't sure was vital. I was given a specific number that I have to reverse. But I thought it might have just been a test number and then the code would work universally for any number. Expectations are never 100% clear with this professor. 

If it does matter the number is 45712090 and must look like 09021754

Comment: And no i'm not asking for the exact code, but if you could lead me in the right direction. I already thought I had the solution. But the problem I posted in the original post is verbatim from my assignment.

Comment: @Alex Indeed, you left vital information behind. There are several ways to do that, but I can't guarantee your teacher won't have a last-minute requirement. Are you allowed to convert to a string? Are you allowed to use a while loop instead of a for loop? If not, can you guarantee the number will never be more than N digits long for a known N? If not, are you allowed to compute a logarithm? Are you allowed to print one character at a time without linefeed? I won't try to guess

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut
"Write a Python program that reads an integer from the keyboard and write its reverse to the screen.  You need to use a for loop, don't use the reverse function or a list. You don’t need to include any comments.
 A sample output will look like this:

 Enter an integer: 45712090
 The number 45712090 in reverse is 09021754"

This is as much information as I have on the problem at hand. Converting to a string seems to be off the menu as that is what I did in my original code and was told my solution was incorrect. according to the problem it MUST be a for loop.

Comment: @Alex The problem is: if you convert to a string everything is easy (you know the length, and you can keep the 0). Otherwise it's still possible but it's really absurd. And it's not stated in the constraints that you can't use a string. So if your teacher is not able to state clearly the constraints and stick to it, I can't help much. By the way, "don't use the reverse function" does not mean you can't define your own function.

Comment: I'm not quite sure string reversing is faster. It is casual easy problem for beginners of programming contests. And string reversion there doesn't pass time limit.

Comment: @sashaaero Quick and dirty benchmark: on a 10 digits number the second solution is 5 times fastes than the first. On 2**100 it's 15 times faster. It's to be expected because the necessary divisions are done internally in a compiled loop in str(n), whereas the first solution does the divisions in pure Python.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut that's a bit surprise for me. Yes, for me 2**100 worked 200 times faster as string reversion.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut thank you for devoting time to this question. I appreciate you. I've decided to email my professor and ask him more in depth why my response was incorrect. But he likes to retain feedback for whatever reason so we'll see. Thank you again!

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut "no MAXINT" - loose wording, not intended literally, and even then I got it wrong. The largest-magnitude possible positive integer has its negative counterpart.  The largest-magnitude negative number in a twos-complement machine has no positive counterpart.  But perhaps I'm understanding you at too trivial a level.  Are you saying that Python integers do not correspond to machine integers and can be as large as you want them to be without special provision by the programmer? (I use Python but that's a detail that has never mattered to me)

Comment: @dave-not-cutler Python integers are always multiprecision integers. If you want to dig into details, in Python 2 there were two int types (one "short", one multiprecision), but Python would silently switch when needed. In Python 3 there is only one integer type. So there has never been a MAXINT, because integers have always been unlimited.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut So just an update, i had the right code all along. My professor incorrectly marked me wrong after I showed him that my output did what he was asking. Thanks, the code snippets you offered will assuredly help me in the future!

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input())
b = 0 

while(a>0):
    b = b*10 + a%10
    a = a//10

print(b)
```

in while loop we pass the condition, run until a(12345) smaller than 0 initially b =0 so b*10 equals 0 + a(12345)%10 = 5 (will be the last digit of your a) then in next line when you do floor division in your a(12345)//10, it will take out the last digit of your a and becomes 1234 and this loop goes again and check whether a(1234) > 0 then goes to second line this time b= b(5)*10 + a(1234)%10 , b becomes 50 and a becomes 123 this will goes until they will be no digit left in a I hope you get it

Comment: in while loop we pass the condition, run until a(12345) smaller than 0 initially 
b =0 so b*10 equals 0 + a(12345)%10 =  5 (will be the last digit of your a)
then in next line when you do floor division in your a(12345)//10, it will take out the
last digit of your a and becomes 1234 and this loop goes again and check whether
a(1234) > 0 then goes to second line this time b= b(5)*10 + a(1234)%10 , b becomes 50 and a becomes 123
this will goes until they will be no digit left in a                                                                                     I hope you get it.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation! Note that you can also [edit] your original answer to add your explanation there.

Answer (score -1):

```
a=56
b=str(a)
for i in b:
    c=b[::-1]
    print(c)
```